# Non-programming question about Japanese encodings: japanese or stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Should I ask the following question here, or on Stackoverflow, or somewhere [else](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2578/philosophy)?

*At work I come accross a lot of Japanese text files in SHIFT-JIS and other encodings.

It causes many mojibake problems for all computer users.

Why is not everybody switching from Japanese-specific encodings to UTF-8?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doesn't strike me as being related to Japanese (the language) at all. On Stackoverflow I'd vote to close it as subjective & argumentative, since there's often no real answer for *"why isn't"* questions. Maybe programmers.stackexchange.com is the best place to ask.

Comment: The answer, BTW, would be pretty much *legacy*. Shift-JIS was used before Unicode became available/popular and many companies are still stuck with it for one reason or another.

Comment: Thanks! http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/82396

Comment: Japanese software industry... slower than dirt at utilizing new software/standards.

Comment: @Mark: I wouldn't say that the Japanese software industry is slow, but it sure is quite insular (well, both literally and figuratively :)). It seems like it mostly has problem to adapt to **international** standards. :(

Comment: my comment was not limited to international standards, but includes processes and overall skill in general. Lacks of DMS, bug tracker, back-office system, and relying heavily on excel files and print-outs is no way to run an efficient company, but i digress from the original topic.

Comment: That's not just Japanese companies unfortunately. :( But I understand. It's just that it seems to me that Japanese standards like the JIS character set, EPWING dictionaries and i-mode were quickly adopted. Ok, that's really off-topic now...

Answer (score 0):

I don't like that particular question, but if someone was asking "How can I set Windows-XP-chan to use Shift-JS?" (I don't know if that's a valid question), I'd suggest asking at Super User.